# Let $f$ be a function defined over $(0,\infty)$ differentiable twice...

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm given a function $f$ that is defined over the interval $(0,\infty)$. Given $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$, $\lim_{x\to \infty}f''(x)$ are finite, I have to prove $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=0$.
I tried supposing the limit of the first derivative isn't zero and then I have to split into 3 cases $(a \in \mathbb{R},+\infty,-\infty)$ and it wasn't useful..

Comment: There are 2 subquestions in this question. One of them is (hopefully) proving that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists. The second one is supposing that this limit exists, what should it be? A hint for the second question is: if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = \epsilon > 0,$ what can we say about $f(x) - f(N)$ for $N$ a large number and $x \to \infty$?

Comment: I can elaborate further if you want but it's probably instructive to think about this more. To prove that the limit exists, by the way, you need to first prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f''(x) = 0$ (this is for similar reasoning as above.)

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed referring to the first question, doesn't proving the limit of the first derivative as $x\to \infty$ implies the limit of the function itself as $x\to \infty$ as infinite?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you are saying here: if you could rephrase that would be helpful. Are you asking if proving the limit of the first derivative exists implies the existence (or can be used to calculate) the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$? The answer is not usually (think of $f(x) = \ln(x)$.) In the case of this question, there is a way to directly show $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists and what the limit is by first showing $\lim_{x \to \infty}f''(x) = 0$, and then using Taylor's theorem in a subtle way.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed Are you sure we need to show $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f''(x)=0$? It seems to me that we can simply use the mean value theorem twice and only need that $\sup_{x>c} \vert f''(x)\vert<\infty$ for some $c>0$.

Comment: I mean using the MVT twice yields $$\vert f'(x)\vert \leq \vert \frac{f(x)-f(x-\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}\vert + \varepsilon \sup_{y\in (x-\varepsilon,x)} \vert f''(y)\vert.$$ The first term is small as $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists and the second one is small as the second derivative is bounded.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven That works too, nice catch. Technically with the Taylor series approach, you don't actually need to have $\lim_{x \to \infty} f''(x)= 0$ either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick $\varepsilon>0$ and $x>0$. Then using first the triangle inequality and then the mean value theorem twice we get

\begin{align*}
 \vert f'(x)\vert &\leq \vert \frac{f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)}{\varepsilon} \vert + \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\vert f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)-f'(x)\varepsilon\vert\\
&\leq \frac{f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)}{\varepsilon} \vert + \varepsilon \sup_{y\in (x,x+\varepsilon)} \vert f''(y)\vert.
\end{align*}

Now we want to show that we can make those terms small for large $x$. Define $a=\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} f(t)$ and note that

$$ \vert f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)\vert
\leq \vert f(x)-a\vert +\vert f(x+\varepsilon)-a\vert.$$

Thus, there exists $x_\varepsilon>0$ such that for all $x\geq x_\varepsilon$ we have

$$\vert f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)\vert \leq \varepsilon^2.$$

Furthermore, as $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} f''(t)$ exists and is finite, we get (as $f''$ is continuous) that for $x\geq 1$ (replace $1$ by your favourite positive number if you like)

$$\sup_{y\in (x,x+\varepsilon)} \vert f''(y)\vert \leq \sup_{y\in (1,\infty)} \vert f''(y)\vert =:C<\infty.$$

Thus, we get for all $x\geq x_\varepsilon+1$

$$\vert f'(x)\vert \leq \frac{\varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon} + C\varepsilon =(C+1)\varepsilon.$$

As $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we get

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x)=0.$$

Note that we do not need the continuity of $f''$, we would just need to replace $1$ by a sufficiently large number $K$ such that $\sup_{y\in (K,\infty)} \vert f''(y)\vert$ is finite (such $K$ is guaranteed to exist as $f''$ has finite limit at infinity). In fact we could also weaken the assumption that $f''$ has a finite limit at infinity to the condition $\sup_{y\in (K,\infty)} \vert f''(y)\vert <\infty$ for some $K>0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry but I didn't quite understand what you did in the first step, can you explain further please?

Comment: @Fairuz_ Which part is unclear to you?

Comment: The start of the proof, where you mentioned the triangle inequality and MVT. If you can please simplify it I think I can work my way to the end of the proof.

Comment: The first step is the triangle inequality in the form $$\vert a\vert =\vert a-b+b\vert \leq\vert a-b\vert +\vert b\vert.$$ For the second step I write $$f(x+\varepsilon)-f(x)=f'(\xi_x)\varepsilon$$ and then $$f'(\xi_x)-f'(x)=f''(\Xi_x)(\xi_x-x),$$ where $\xi_x\in (x,x+\varepsilon)$ and $\Xi_x\in (x,\xi_x)$. I leave the rest to you.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it. I'm just used to write the MVT in a different way.

Comment: @Fairuz_ Oh, how do you usually write the MVT?

Comment: I verify continuity in a certain closed interval $[a,b]$ and differentiability in $(a,b)$ and then $\exists c \in (a,b)$ s.t $f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. So it's the same if we're observing the interval $(x,x+\epsilon)$ it just seemed unfamiliar for me in the first glance

Comment: @Fairuz_ I see. Writing it as a fraction is useful to get the geometric intuition, however, typically you'll apply it in the version I used. It's good to have both form in your mind.